# SCSS media query embedded in class styling - GitHub says syntax error, but it compiles?

Tags: github, sass, syntax-error

My SCSS file compiles with no errors, so why does GitHub say there is a syntax error at the at symbol (`@`) in my media query?

[image: screen-capture from GitHub showing syntax error highlighting]

I have a media query (`@media(min-width: $break-medium)`) nested within a class's styling, just like described in the [official docs](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#media). It compiles without errors and the CSS it generates behaves as I expect. But GitHub is highlighting it as a syntax error.

Is this an issue with GitHub or my code? I'm fairly new to SCSS so I wanted to ask here before submitting an issue on GitHub.

Comment: I think it is some default behaviour of GitHub. I have a lot of SCSS files for a project and all the `@` signs for media queries are red.

Comment: @SuperDJ would you agree that that is incorrect behavior? It's very minor, but I think I may go ahead and submit an issue.

Comment: Since the scss markup is correct I would say that is incorrect behaviour yes. When inspecting the `@` sign it is wrapped in a `.pl.ii` class. When googling that class there seems to be a lot more questions about it. 

You can always submit it as an issue and see what GitHub thinks of it.

Comment: Turns out there is already an open issue to deal with this.

https://github.com/MarioRicalde/SCSS.tmbundle/pull/195

That's the repo that is used by Linguist, which is the repo used by Github to do syntax highlighting.

cc @MarioRicalde